# Summation Simplification Confusion

Tags: summation

> $$(1/2)\sum_{i = 0}^{n/2 - 1} i - \sum_{i = 0}^{n/2 - 1} 1$$

Would this require the use of the following identitiy for the first summation:

> $$ \frac{n(n+1)}{2} $$

I attempted to simplify and ended up with:

> $$ (1/2)( \frac{n^2}{8}- \frac{n}{2}) + \frac{1}{2}$$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first sum using Gauss' method:

$$\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left({\frac{n}{2}-1}\right)\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}{2}$$

The second sum using constant rule:

$$\frac{n}{2}$$

Therefore:

$$\frac{\frac{n^2}{4}-\frac{2n}{4}}{4}-\frac{n}{2}$$

Simplifying:

$$\frac{n^2-10n}{16}$$

Compare this with your work (which isn't posted) to see where you went wrong.

Comment: The second term is not $\frac n2 -1$. There are $\frac n2$ terms you see... counting from $0$

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: Ah I see where I made my mistake. Thanks!

Comment: @LanierFreeman, you mentioned in my other post that I would need to use an identity. Why use Gauss' method here?

Comment: We can use Gauss' method here because we have a lower bound of $0$ or $1$, summand of $i$, and a finite upper bound expression.

Comment: Ah. nevermind, lol I see it now. Its late, thanks again!

Comment: No problem @TacoB0t!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36199/discussion-between-tacob0t-and-lanier-freeman).

Answer (score 0):

You are not quite right.

You get $\frac 12\frac{(\frac n2 -1 )\frac n2}2 - \frac n2 = \frac 12( \frac {n^2}8 - \frac n4) - \frac n2$

Comment: Hmmmm ok. Is the -1 simply dropped from the second summation ?

Comment: @TacoB0t $-1$ is not dropped. It is just that there are $\frac n2$ terms.